# possible prime factors of $4^{444}+3$

Tags: number-theory

I have not factored the number $4^{444}+3$ yet. I wonder, though, if there are
 restrictions for possible prime factors p. The only obvious restriction is,
 that -3 must be a quadratic residue of p. Are there more useful restrictions,
 such as in the case of mersenne numbers ?

Comment: maple said it is composite, but when I used the 'easy' option (which only looks for relatively small prime factors), it didn't find any.

Comment: Just out of interest, how long would factoring a number like that take?

Comment: [This site](http://www.alpertron.com.ar/ECM.HTM) claims it's composite, but after 10 minutes (so far), it's still attempting to find a factor.

Comment: The site contains an applet that does elliptic curve factorization; it shouldn't kill the site.  The work should be done on client machines, not on the server.

Comment: @rgettman: In the mean time, the link worked again (that's why I deleted my comment). Anyway, the smiley should have been a giveaway that I didn't really think you killed that site (although I certainly didn't know that the work is done client-side).

Comment: It is much easier to check, if a number is composite, than

Comment: to find a factor. It can take very long to factor such a

Comment: number. 268 digits is very much.

Comment: @Peter: Is there a reason why you split your sentence into three comments? While the comment length is restricted, it is not restricted *that* much.

Comment: Yes, the comment window closed before I finished

Comment: @Peter: Did you possibly press Enter? Because that tells SE that you've finished the comment. Anyway, up to 5 minutes after you've submitted it, you can still edit it using the "edit" link at its end.

Comment: consider running a routine to see if it fits any gaussian factorable forms (example sum of square or sum of cubes or sum of 4th powers etc...)... Once you find such a form you can then factor it over the gaussian integers and then repeatedly factor those as well. Likely this will not work but a check for a list of about 10 or so factorable forms (sum of squares, cubes, fifth powers, 7th powers, 11th powers etc...) will be quick compared to most other factoring methods. Its not guaranteed to work but its worth a shot

Comment: Killed the applet factorization after 1 hour.  It claims that any factor has a 100% chance of having at least 20 digits in the factor.

Comment: In Fact, the smallest factor probably has 40 digits or more. The best method is ECM (elliptic curve method). The quadratic sieve is faster, but in case of such a big number, it takes a very long time.

Comment: GMP-ECM is a great program which I used to factor this number, without success yet.

Comment: Is there any reason why you'd like to factor this number in particular? At ~900 bits, it's well beyond the current [factorization records](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_factorization_records) for numbers of general form.

Comment: As I wrote, I would be more interested in filtering possible prime factors. I tried the factorization just as a challange to myself, knowing that perhaps I will never find the factorization.

Comment: @PeterKošinár: But the number is not of general form! It's quite doable with SNFS. Extrapolating from Childers' record factorization I estimate 8 CPU-years, or 12 months on an 8-core machine.

Comment: @Charles I fully agree that a some factoring methods might be a lot more successful for number of this form -- my remark was only aimed at the fact that the initial comments were referring to ECM; which is a general factoring algorithm.

Comment: @PeterKošinár: Ah. A full factorization with ECM is surely hopeless. It might be possible to pull a factor out with it, though, which might make the number easier to finish with other methods.

Comment: If ECM finds a prime factor and the cofactor is prime, the factorizaion IS finished. So with some luck, ECM can do the job. But this cannot be foreseen.